# hystrix circuit open event

Tags: spring, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

I have configured the spring aspect for hystrixcommand and it works fine ( Open and Close circuit )

During my testing , what I observed is that when the circuit is open , the normal flow is still invoked and on the event FAILURE , the fall back is invoked.

What i understand from the documentation is that  , when the circuit is open , the normal flow will be checked only once in five seconds ( default ) . I tried manually setting the value to 20 seconds , but still did not work

```
@HystrixCommand(commandProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds", value = "20000")
        },
            fallbackMethod = "fallbackCall")
```

Where do i set this configuration ? i do not want the error service to be invoked every time and then go to the fallback.

Answer (score 4):

The test i was doing had incorrect configuration.
In order to SHORT_CIRCUIT , circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold should be met.

The default value was 20 and number of failures in the rolling window was not exceeding 20 in my case . So short circuit never happened. Below is the documentation I got from another stack over flow response

> within a timespan of duration `metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds`, the percentage of actions resulting in a handled exception exceeds `errorThresholdPercentage`, provided also that the number of actions through the circuit in the timespan is at least `requestVolumeThreshold`

I set circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold to 1 and it works as expected.